# DocuSign Implicit code grant access token not readable from browser url section?

Tags: docusignapi

**Background**:- I'm trying to implement the Implicit Grant REST API of DocuSign.

According to the documentation provided by DocuSign:-

After consent has been granted, the Authentication Service verifies that the client application is valid and has access to the requested scope. If so, it redirects the access token to the provided callback URI in a hash fragment.

The **response** contains the following hash fragment parameters:

> http://localhost/#access_token=eyJ0eXAi.....9LyiFrUqvdw&expires_in=28800&token_type

**Problem statement:-**
After redirection we are trying to read the access token from the hash fragment of url section, but we are facing below issue:-

We are trying to open docusign window through iframe, we are getting the below error

> Refused to display
> https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=token&scope=signature&client_id=cab75309-6eb3-4969-a15d-fff35513e179&redirect_uri=https://www.sirionlabs.com/
> in a frame because it set '**X-Frame-Options**' to '**sameorigin**'

So we tried to login to docusign app in another browser tab and then we are not able to read access token from the user, though we are getting the token printed on browser console.

How can we read the token received after login-in to Docusign service, so we can redirect that token to our app for further processing?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an **iframe** for DocuSign authentication.
This is a security concern.

Users must see the URL at the top to know it's DocuSign and secure etc.

Please use a different window or redirect.

Comment: Hi @Inbar Gazit  I proceeded with approach suggested by you. But still we are facing some issue.
how to read the value after hash in docusign url. Can we change # to ‘?’

I have tried following scenarios:-

1. When there is # in url then angular considers it as route and created route does not matches because token is unique for every call.
2. When accessToken is taken as route parameter then I removes token from the url automatically on redirection
3. When tried to call backend api directly, then also it created issue. As the redirect url contains hash fragment it cant hit api directly

Comment: You can also not use a # in redirectURI. This is not just DocuSign, the OAuth2.0 specification specifically does not allow for this character.

Comment: You can, however, pass parameters using the &state= parameter and get them back on the other side if that helps.

Comment: Sorry I did not get how adding state parameter will help in reading access token. This parameter is used to avoid Cross-Site Request Forgery . We are trying to read the access token returned in hash fragment. Please help us how in reading the access token at client level from browser url section and send it to back end for further processing.

Comment: what is your redirectUri? it has the # character? that is not allowed. To fix the issue, use a URL that does not contain the # character.

Comment: Hi @Inbar Gazit- We don't have "#" in our redirect_uri. Here is the sample redirect_uri "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=token&scope=signature&client_id=cab75309-6eb3-4969-a15d-fff35513****&redirect_uri=https://sdemo.sirioninc.com/"
We are getting "#" in callback url provided by docusign, in which docusign sends access_token. Here is the sample callback url from docusign " https://sdemo.sirioninc.com/web/docusign/callback#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJNVxpires_in=28800&token_type=bearer